# No MOTD on first login after upgrade to 13.10

Tags: 13.10, motd

One of my favorite things when I installed Ubuntu Server 10.04LTS was the MOTD with the landscape-common data.  After updating to 13.10 and having some trouble at first with MOTD not working at all, it finally does work, but not during the first login.  Once I exit and log back in, then the MOTD does show.